# python module multi-version

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I've installed `tensorflow-rocm` which requires `typing-extension-4.5.0`. When I'm trying to install `torch` from the official repo which requires `typing-extension-4.8.0`, the installer automatically uninstalls the lower version module.
Actually, I've created a virtual environment in `~/.local`, and don't want to create another one for `torch`. Is there a method to let different modules choose their dependencies by path or some other way?

I used to create a different environment for those modules, but does there exist a method to let different modules choose their dependencies by path or some other way?

Comment: Virtual environments **are** that method.

Comment: You can run two separate applications in two different virtual environments, which have different versions installed. That is the point of virtual environments. But you cannot have one application (one process, to be precise) use two different versions of a library at the same time, if that is what your are asking.

Comment: Am I correct that `tensorflow-rocm` does not work with the newer version of the `typnig-extension`?

Comment: Did you follow the ROCm documentation regarding torch? `pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/rocm5.6/` from https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/3rd-party/pytorch-install.html

Comment: Wow, this problem has been solved by upgrading rocm to version 6.0.0. Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create another virtual environment.

If you really don't want to use these virtual environments, I think you can download the different versions of the package into a folder on your computer. Then import what you need from the correct folder, indicating its path. (not really sure if it works)